# How to do with iOS gifting IAP?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

By Apple App Store Guidelines description

[App Store Review Guidelines - Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#content-codes)

> 3.1.1
>           Apps may enable gifting of items that are eligible for in-app purchase to others. 
>           Such gifts may only be refunded to the original purchaser and may not be exchanged.

I have two questions

1. Does gifting IAP function provided by system now?
2. Or it just means we can do gifting IAP behavior by ourself?

EX: Keep the purchase information in our server and to handle the gifting behavior.

Comment: It is up to you to handle the gifting; e.g. the user may purchase 1000 "coins" and use it to purchase a skin - this skin can then be gifted, using your server, to another player.

Comment: Thanks~~~~~~~ ^^